# PHP/DOMDocument - How can i get elements which do not have specific class

Tags: php, domdocument

This is the code i use so far:

```
$urlIn1 = "http://www.sportsdirect.com/slazenger-mens-canvas-shoes-246033?colcode=24603325";
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); 
$docIn1 = new DOMDocument();
$docIn1->loadHTMLFile($urlIn1);

$docIn1->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$docIn1->formatOutput = true;

$xpathIn1 = new DOMXpath($docIn1);
$Price = $xpathIn1->query('//span[@id="dnn_ctr103511_ViewTemplate_ctl00_ctl07_ctl01_lblSellingPrice"]')->item(0)->nodeValue;

echo $Price;
```

With this code i `echo` the price.

**My question is:**

How can i get all the values from the options from the select menu with id `dnn_ctr103511_ViewTemplate_ctl00_ctl09_sizeDdl` which do **NOT** have `class='greyOut'`.

After i get all the values from the options from the select menu i have to format them in one line looking like this.

**Expected final result:**

`7 (41), 7.5 (41.5), 8 (42), 8.5 (42.5), 9 (43), 9.5 (43.5), 10 (44), 11 (45), 12 (46)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this xpath expression to get the wanted options from the select menu with id `dnn_ctr103511_ViewTemplate_ctl00_ctl09_sizeDdl`:

> //select[@id="dnn_ctr103511_ViewTemplate_ctl00_ctl09_sizeDdl"]/option[not(contains(@class,
>   "greyOut")) and not(contains(@selected, "selected"))]

Then you can loop the result from the [DOMXPath::query](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) and create an array with all the prices and use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to create your one line presentation.

For example:

```
$urlIn1 = "http://www.sportsdirect.com/slazenger-mens-canvas-shoes-246033?colcode=24603325";
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$docIn1 = new DOMDocument();
$docIn1->loadHTMLFile($urlIn1);

$docIn1->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$docIn1->formatOutput = true;

$xpathIn1 = new DOMXpath($docIn1);
$domNodeList = $xpathIn1->query('//select[@id="dnn_ctr103511_ViewTemplate_ctl00_ctl09_sizeDdl"]/option[not(contains(@class, "greyOut")) and not(contains(@selected, "selected"))]');

$prices = array();
foreach ($domNodeList as $domElement) {
    $prices[] = $domElement->nodeValue;
}

echo implode(', ', $prices);
```